# How can i detect user login and logout events in asp.net core application hosted in windows service?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services

I have an asp.net core 3.0 application hosted in windows service. I used approach in [following documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). How can i detect user login and logout session changes in my code ?

I tried to create ServiceBase with OnSessionChange override but i do not know how to start or register it and i am not sure this is a valid approach.
I also tried to use `services.AddHostedService<IHostedService>() method` but there is no way to handle session change events in IHostedService.

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<SessionChangesListener>();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Comment: What is your authentication schema? How will you login and logout?

Comment: I want to detect windows user session changes events so when user loggs in, loggs out, switches account on windows. It has nothing to do with asp net core authentication.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?